# Progressbar Value Not Valid

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am somewhat new to this so forgive me, I am making a simple music player with a progress bar that displays the current duration of the song. When I play a song that is about 3:50 the following error displays after the song ends:

```
Additional information: Value of '231' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
```

However a song that was 5 minutes long doesn't display this error so I am a bit confused. The part of the code that seems to be the problem:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration
    ProgressBar1.Value = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
    ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
End Sub
```

Specifically the error points to:

```
ProgressBar1.Value = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
```

Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. The relevant parts pieces are 1) The length of the song 2) The maximum that is set for the song 3) The value that is set when it causes an exception. It's apparent you're trying to set a value over the specified maximum, but it's not really possible to say why.

Comment: `ProgressBar1.Increment(1)` is probably unnecessary, setting `ProgressBar1.Value` should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that when the song ends, its `Ctlcontrols.currentPosition` property can take on the value of `currentMedia.duration` + 1, probably due to fractional seconds of duration being rounded internally.  It would appear to me that there is an inconsistency in how rounding is performed between these two procedures.

Your best bet is to make the following change:

```
ProgressBar1.Value = Math.Min(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition, AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration)
```

Comment: Made the code change as well as removed the unnecessary piece of code you mentioned above and everything seems to be working perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First Get the total second of the song then try to compute for the 100% value of the duration of the song that will generate the increment value for the progress bar example:

3:50min = 230seconds / 100 = 2.3

it means that you have to increment your progress bar by 2.3 in every second to 230seconds...